# Do I have to initialize Dali lamp somehow if I use broadcast commands?

Tags: protocol, dali

I have few Dali lamps. Some of them are new, some of them are used. It is hard to tell which was initialized (addressed?) and which was not.

I have simple DALI circuit with microcontroller and simple application that uses broadcast addressing and it sends STEP_UP_AND_ON, SET_DIRECT_ARC_LEVEL and OFF commands.

The problem is that only few lamps work.

**Do I have to address lamps before I send some commands?**

**Is this possible (normal?) that new lamps are not reacting for broadcast commands at all?**

Answer (score 1):

No, the presence or absence of a short address does not affect whether it reacts to broadcast commands. The only legitimate reason to not react to broadcast commands is if the Operating Mode is non zero, so try setting that (to 0) if your controller can send it (added in Edition 2).

Another way you can have this effect is if you controller is sending malformed commands (bit timings, message spacing, encoding) so if you have built that yourself you should check the messages on a scope. It is possible to send messages that are marginal so you are getting inconsistent results. But this shouldn’t be the case for a commercial controller.

Comment: The only controller I have is my board with microcontroller. What frame should I send to lamps to set Operating Mode? I found command like this: "252 YAAA AAA1 1111 1100 QUERY OPERATING MODE" but there is no SET OPERATING MODE in command list I'm using.

Comment: Set Operating Mode sets it to the value of DTR0, so first send DTR0 with value 0, then send Set Operating Mode which is opcode byte 0x23. This is a Send Twice command (within 100ms) for it to take effect.

Comment: To set value of DTR0 I have to: set level to 0 and then save current level in DTR0; right? Where I can find informations like this? I cant find any good documentation about DALI2.

Comment: No, you don't touch the level to set DTR0 to 0. DTR0 is the old DTR from Edition 1, command number 257, opcode 0xA3. Information about DALI-2 and links to the standards are [here](https://www.digitalilluminationinterface.org/dali/standards.html)